# Javascript - For each Name set ID equal to Name[i] AND validate

Tags: javascript, validation

Okay I've created an invoice where depending on the number of invoiced items, it will generate a check box next to each one for approval. Each checkbox will have the name `invoiceApproval`.

So far my script will count to see how many inputs have the name `invoiceApproval` then assign an ID to each one with the ID = `invoiceApproval[i]`

That is working perfectly, but now when I use the [JavaScript Form Validation : quick and easy! in HTML Forms](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) to assign a `frmvalidator.addValidation` for each ID (the number of each being equal to how many checkboxes have the name `invoiceApproval`) it only validates the first box with the ID `invoiceApproval0`.

Why will my 'for each' only work for the first instance??? What am I doing wrong here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("forminvoice"); 

    var inva = document.getElementsByName("invoiceApproval");
    for (var i = 0; i < inva.length;i++) {
        var inc = "invoiceApproval"+[i];
        inva[i].setAttribute("id",inc); 
    }


    var inva = document.getElementsByName("invoiceApproval");
    for (var i = 0; i < inva.length;i++) {
        var inc = "invoiceApproval"+[i];
        frmvalidator.addValidation(inc,"shouldselchk=x","You must check off each item on the right hand side of the invoice before you can submit approval.");
    }
</script>
```

And the PHP loop that generates the checkboxes is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox'  value='x' name ='invoiceApproval' > Approve";  
}
```

Comment: It could be helpful to show an example of the generated HTML also.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any particular reason you're using `[i]` instead of `i`?

Comment: Why not just add the `i` in the PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The library's code is using

```
var itemobj = this.formobj[itemname];
```

to retrieve the form item. Later it does

```
if (itemobj.length && isNaN(itemobj.selectedIndex))
{
    itemobj = itemobj[0];
}
```

Which means that if there are multiple items with the same name, it will always choose the first one. Taking names for references to your form fields is such bad practice

The only solution (if you want to work with this library, but I would stay away from it, it's really poorly written) is to make your names not be the same.

**Side Note**

The line

```
var inc = "invoiceApproval"+[i];
```

Is creating an array with a single value in it, and then toString is being called on it, and `toString` (luckily for you) returns a single value array as the value itself. Get rid of those brackets, it should be

```
var inc = "invoiceApproval"+i;
```